Getting stable polygon geometry values from an MVT-format VectorTileLayer in OpenLayers?
I am trying to identify points inside polygons using Turf.js in combination with OpenLayers 9. The polygons I show on my OpenLayers map load a lot faster if I use VectorTileLayers with a format of MVT instead of VectorLayers, as you'd expect. Unfortunately, the fact that zooming in and out on a VectorTileLayer affects the geometry returned makes it so that results from the pointsWithinPolygon function are often wrong; for example, I can count 5 points within the selected polygon in my viewport and if I zoom out far enough it will return 5, if I zoom in too close it will return 4 (even though 5 are still physically visible within in my viewport).
Based on how the OpenLayers documentation reads, I thought maybe setting the MVT property featureClass to Feature would give me access to stable geometry values, but it doesn't appear to do so.
It seems like my only option is to

Load a VectorTileLayer that a user can click on
When the user selects a polygon, create a VectorLayer using a WFS request with a CQL Filter that looks for the feature ID of the polygon the user clicked on
Display the VectorLayer with the selected polygon(s) highlighted and get the geometry of the feature(s) from this layer

When I tested using a VectorLayer and zooming in/out and finding points within selected polygons, the geometry able to be retrieved is stable and it works very well; I always get 5 points returned no matter how far zoomed in or out I am (in reference to my earlier example above). This seems like a clunky workaround though, especially if my user is selecting multiple polygons very quickly; is there another way I could do this utilizing the VectorTileLayer instead?
This is the VectorTileLayer and VectorTileSource definition:
const hucVectorSource = new VectorTileSource({
  url:
    'https://mywebsite.com/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/' +
    `${workspace}` +
    '%3A' +
    'huc_8' +
    '@EPSG%3A' +
    '900913' +
    '@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf',
  format: new MVT({
    featureClass: Feature,
  }),
});

export const huc8Layer = new VectorTileLayer({
  opacity: 1,
  visible: true,
  declutter: true,
  source: hucVectorSource,
  renderMode: 'hybrid' //I have tried 'vector' here as well, doesn't make a difference
  style: hucStyleFunc as StyleFunction,
  properties: { name: 'huc8' },
  zIndex: 1,
});

Using pointsWithinPolygon function from Turf.js:
//Get the user-selected polygons derived from the huc8Layer (VectorTileLayer) on the map.
const hucFeatures = Object.values(selectedHucs) as Feature<Geometry>[];

//Write features to GeoJSON object, reprojecting to EPSG 4326 for use with Turf.js
const hucGjson = new GeoJSON();
const gjHucFeats = hucGjson.writeFeaturesObject(hucFeatures, {
  dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
  featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
});

//Get the point layer from the map
const layersOnMap = mapObj.getAllLayers();
const ehaOpLyr = layersOnMap.filter((lyr) => lyr.get('name') == 'ehaOperational')[0] as VectorLayer<VectorSource<Feature<Geometry>>>;
const ehaOpSrc: VectorSource<Feature<Geometry>> = ehaOpLyr.getSource();

//Write features to GeoJSON object, reprojecting to EPSG 4326 for use with Turf.js
const ehaOpGjson = new GeoJSON();
const ehaOpPtFeats = ehaOpGjson.writeFeaturesObject(ehaOpSrc.getFeatures(), {
  dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
  featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
});

//Create feature collections in Turf.js and find where points intersect the polygons
const hucFC = featureCollection(gjHucFeats.features) as FeatureCollection<MultiPolygon, { [name: string]: any }>;
const pointsFC = featureCollection(ehaOpPtFeats.features) as FeatureCollection<Point, { [name: string]: any }>;
const pointsInside = pointsWithinPolygon(pointsFC, hucFC);
console.log(pointsInside);


I do not believe there is a way to get stable geometry from MVT-format VectorTileLayers, but I figured out a quicker workaround than my proposed VectorLayer workflow above. This solution works pretty well and negates the need to create a VectorLayer at all. I was reading this stackoverflow thread about loading vector features without adding them to the map and similarly, I wanted to avoid loading a VectorLayer on the map for two reasons:

If I loaded a VectorLayer to show user selections, the layer would flash while resetting the source and updating the display (so every time someone clicks a new polygon to add to their selection - this would be annoying).
Even if I made the VectorLayer invisible with transparent fill and reflected user selections on the VectorTileLayer instead, it would still take many seconds to load the VectorLayer on the map since in order to load the features using VectorSource, you have to turn the layer on in the map. I would have to use the featuresonload event in VectorSource and make the user wait until the layer is ready before they can do anything else.

This led me to see how I could read a response of a WFS request without needing to make a VectorSource (well, not a proper one anyway) or a VectorLayer. I ended up writing a function to get the WFS request URL and then an asynchronous function to fetch the features. Meanwhile, the user can interact with the VectorTileLayer as much as they want and I am able to display their selections in realtime as they click without any flashing between selections. While I haven't done this in my example below, in order to reduce the number of requests hitting the server, it may be a good idea to implement some sort of debouncing, so the user has a second to click however many polygons they want before it makes the async fetch call.
Even though you still have to wait on the asynchronous request which is similar to feature loading, I find not having to load a layer on the actual map cuts down on wait time significantly.
Relevant functions:
const getWfsRequest = (workspace: string, layerName: string, filter?: string[]) => {
  const wfsUrl =
    `https://mywebsite.com/geoserver/${workspace}/wfs?` +
    'service=wfs&' +
    'version=2.0.0&' +
    'request=GetFeature&' +
    `typeNames=${workspace}:${layerName}&` +
    'outputFormat=application/json&' +
    'srsName=EPSG:3857&' +
    `CQL_FILTER=huc_8 IN (${filter.join(',')})`;
  return wfsUrl;
};

async function getFeatures(requestUrl: string) {
  const response = await fetch(requestUrl, { method: 'GET' });
  if (response.status === 200) {
    return response.json();
  } else {
    console.error('something went wrong');
  }
}

How I implement pointsWithinPolygons function from Turf.js:
//Get the selected HUC (polygon) feature ids
const hucFeatureIds = Object.keys(selectedHucs);

//Get the WFS request URL
const requestUrl = getWfsRequest('myworkspace', 'mylayer', hucFeatureIds);

//Fetch features asynchronously
getFeatures(requestUrl)
  .then((data) => {
    //Read features in JSON to Feature array
    const hucFeatures: Feature<Geometry>[] = new GeoJSON({
      dataProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
      featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
    }).readFeatures(data);

    //Write features to GeoJSON object, reprojecting to EPSG 4326 for use with Turf.js
    const hucGjson = new GeoJSON();
    const gjHucFeats = hucGjson.writeFeaturesObject(hucFeatures, {
      dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
      featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
    });

    //Get the point layer on the map
    const layersOnMap = mapObj.getAllLayers();
    const ehaOpLyr = layersOnMap.filter((lyr) => lyr.get('name') == 'ehaOperational')[0] as VectorLayer<VectorSource<Feature<Geometry>>>;
    const ehaOpSrc: VectorSource<Feature<Geometry>> = ehaOpLyr.getSource();

    //Write features to GeoJSON object, reprojecting to EPSG 4326 for use with Turf.js
    const ehaOpGjson = new GeoJSON();
    const ehaOpPtFeats = ehaOpGjson.writeFeaturesObject(ehaOpSrc.getFeatures(), {
      dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
      featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
    });

    //Create feature collections in Turf.js and find where points intersect the selected HUC areas
    const hucFC = featureCollection(gjHucFeats.features) as FeatureCollection<MultiPolygon, { [name: string]: any }>;
    const pointsFC = featureCollection(ehaOpPtFeats.features) as FeatureCollection<Point, { [name: string]: any }>;
    const pointsInside = pointsWithinPolygon(pointsFC, hucFC);
    console.log(pointsInside);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

